# Set value of array via KeyPath

Tags: swift, swift-keypath

I am trying to update the value stored in an array property of a class via the use of KeyPaths. Here is my code:

```
func listenAndUpdateDocuments<T: JSONDecodable>(
    _ property: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<MyModel, [T]?>,
    from model: MyModel) {
    guard let reference = reference else {
        return
    }
    guard listener == nil else {
        return
    }
    listener = backendClient.listenToDocuments(reference) { [weak model] (result: Result<[T], RequestError>) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let value):
            model?[keyPath: property] = value
        case .failure:
            model?[keyPath: property] = []
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I call this function like this:

```
myListener.listenAndUpdateDocuments(\.viewers, from: self)
```

where `viewers` is of type `[ViewersModel]`, it always comes back with the following error:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

How do I solve this? I have a similar version of the code but where the `property` parameter isn't an array, and that works.

Comment: What if you pass in `\MyModel.viewers`?

Comment: @DávidPásztor It comes back with `Cannot convert value of type 'ReferenceWritableKeyPath<MyModel, [ViewersModel]>' to expected argument type 'ReferenceWritableKeyPath<MyModel, [_]?>'`

Comment: Aha removing the optional `?` on the `ReferenceWritableKeyPath` value worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with something similar:

```
_ = Token.query(on: req).filter(\.expiry < Date()).delete()
```

The solution I found was to use a more up-to-date api to handle my request parameters.

```
_ = Token.query(on: req).filter(\.expiry, .lessThan, Date()).delete()
```

It had less to do with the keypath itself than I thought!